# How to obtain list of devices and their parameters using HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum?

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

How to obtain the content and the main parameters of devices using registry section `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum?`

Well, I need to scan registry tree, containing `..\Enum\{SomeID}\{OneMoreID}\{MyDearValue}`, which should contain some description, i.e. "KINGSTON 100500TB Flash of God". And the main question is: how to obtain all of this string descriptions, using WinAPI and C++?

Comment: What research have you done so far? Which MSDN pages came close but confused you or didn't have _quite_ what you were after?

Comment: The short (and good) answer is: "don't". If you want to enumerate devices, there are better ways than crawling the registry (e.g., use WMI to enumerate `CIM_LogicalDevice`s).

Comment: I've been confused by [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/hardware/ff546173(v=vs.85).aspx), where said, that I shouldn't do it. But university... thinks different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Win32 Registry functions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Not exactly what I need, I suppose. Some more specific function needed for obtaining devices description.